# Adicionar botão embaixo da div utilizando a função after()

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa tarde!

Tenho a seguinte situação:

Várias divs, lado a lado, usando display: inline-block.

Quero que, ao clicar em uma div, eu consiga colocar um botão **embaixo** desta div.

Eu comecei usando a função append do jQuery, da seguinte forma:

```
   $(".classeDaDiv").click(function() { 
      $(this).append("<button>Titulo</button>");
   })
```

Sem problemas até aí, fez o que eu queria. O problema é que eu preciso remover este botão ao clicar novamente na div. Então implementei isso também. Eu estou

Answer (score 0):

Para inserir um elemento após o que foi clicado você deve utilizar a função `insertAfter` do jQuery.

Troque o seu código, para o seguinte:

```
$(".classeDaDiv").click(function() {
   $('<button>Titulo</button>').insertAfter(this);
});
```